# How can I create a LUT on Linux with free and open source software?

Tags: color-correction, linux

I use Linux for everything media production. I shoot RAW and process images with Darktable.

Now that I've started making videos too (4K ProRes), I need to apply a LUT to them in post. This requires importing a .cube file into Kdenlive. I know how to do that, but I don't know how to *create* a LUT.

Can I import a frame of video into Darktable, adjust the colors, and export a .cube file to import into Kdenlive to apply to the video?

Or are there other programs that will create a LUT on Linux? Can GIMP do it?

**What Linux program can be used to *create* LUTs?**

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution myself. Just as a starting point: Check out a .cube file, it's plain text. Also the specification might help, found it here: https://kono.phpage.fr/images/a/a1/Adobe-cube-lut-specification-1.0.pdf

Comment: This article - https://streamshark.io/obs-guide/converting-cube-3dl-lut-to-image - supplies a neutral lut image file. With a bit of programming skills it should be possible to code ones own .cube file generator. There seems to be an online generator (I know it's not exactly what you want) - https://www.onlinelutcreator.com/lutcreator - but it's necessary to sign up. Didn't try it, yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for that kind of software as well.
Then I found the .cube specification.

I thought to myself ... an average programmer should be able to do it in a couple of days ... and then I did the job ;-)

It's called ***lutcraft***, a command line tool written in python3.

You can find it on github:

https://github.com/EinExperte/lutcraft

Instruction:

> 1. Create a neutral png image

```
lutc lut-neutral.png
```

> 2. Manipulate the colors of the image
>
> Do pixel-level color adjustments as desired.
>
> Tools I suggest are darktable, gimp, flowblade or cinelerra. Any other program doing pixel-level imaging will do fine.
>
> Then save the image. I assume you call the file lut-x.png.
>
> 3. Convert the image into a lookup table (.cube file)

```
lutc -i lut-x.png lut-x.cube
```

> This will output a 3D lookup tabble corresponding to the file lut-x.cube

If you have any questions / suggestions / etc., feel free to comment or e-mail me.